# Unpacking data from a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, unpack

I would like to know how to unpack data from a struct in C. I'm basically trying to send a message from a client and I want the message to be unpacked when received by the server and I would like these co-ordinates to be displayed in the original order.

Here is my struct:

```
void person_info(info *person) {
    person.firstname = "sam";
    person.lastname = "Bayleys";
    person.age = 17;
}
```

How could this be unpacked on the server side?

Comment: That's definitely not a struct. That's a function. I also doubt that compiles since you're using the `.` operator instead of the `->` operator on the `person` pointer.

Comment: Well, how are you packing it on the client side?

Comment: How are you packing it?

Comment: Look up 'serialization' and TLV (type, length, value) encoding.  There are many ways to do it; it depends on what else you might need to send to the server on the same type of connection.  The server needs to know what it is being sent (hence the TLV encoding), but there'll be a higher level protocol — are you sending data to be stored in a database, to be updated, to be queried, deleted, analyzed or what?  The same information might be associated with lots of different actions, and you need to know which is appropriate.